# Verifying signatures

Tags: openssl, blockchain, signature, verify, crt

I'm trying to verify some signatures corresponding to some transactions. The transactions were created by issuing:

echo 'A,B,EUR,1,30'|openssl dgst -sha256 -sign A.key -out A.signature

To perform the verification, I have the signature file A.signature and the associated A.crt file.

I'm doing this:

openssl x509 -in A.crt -pubkey -noout > file.txt
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify file.txt -signature A.signature trx.txt

where trx.txt contains A,B,EUR,1,30.

The verification is failing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume trx.txt does not actually end with a period (.) and that was just you putting data within a prose sentence; but does it end with one, and only one, newline character (which is invisible)?

Comment: Yes. I've removed the ending \n by using "tr".

Comment: That's the problem. The data you signed (output by `echo`) DOES have a newline, and a digital signature will verify only if the data verified is EXACTLY the same as the data signed, which means it must contain the same newline.